# Is there any way to prohibit the screen from scrolling when moving input type=range?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When you move input type=range, which is placed vertically, the screen scrolls with it.
Is there any way to prohibit the scrolling when moving input?

[image]

I have prepared a [demo](https://77uh1.csb.app/).
You can check this issue by sizing the screen for mobile devices in the Developer Tools.
[Demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-shaw-77uh1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for CSS `touch-action: none`, which should be placed on the element you wish to interact with without scrolling the view (in this case, the input).

```
      <input
        type="range"
        onChange={changeInput}
        style={{ transform: "rotate(90deg)", "touch-action": "none" }}
      />
```

[Here's your code updated with this change.](https://hwucp.csb.app/)